# What happens when two semaphores change simultaneously and one of the two cannot decrement immediately?

Tags: c, posix, ipc, semaphore, atomic

Consider this code:

```
struct sembuf s_op[2];

s_op[0].sem_num = old;
s_op[0].sem_op = 1;
s_op[0].sem_flg = 0;
s_op[1].sem_num = new;
s_op[1].sem_op = -1;
s_op[1].sem_flg = 0;
semop(semid, s_op, 2);
```

Now, if "new" cannot be decremented immediately (because it is already at 0), will there be a time interval in which the "old" semaphore has been increased and the "new" one has not?
I mean, can this always happen **atomically**?

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/semop.html https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html: "The semop() function shall perform atomically a user-defined array of semaphore operations on the set of semaphores associated with the semaphore identifier specified by the argument semid."

Comment: How the processor do that? If it test-and-set two variables in the same atomic operation and one of the two fails, it should "undo" the operation that succeeded and therefore the operation would no longer be atomic, right?

Comment: (Sorry - I missed the title and commented on question in the question). It's implemented by kernel or libc. The simplest approach is just to have a global lock but this would be bad for performance. Actual implementation likely is more complicated. 
In general you won't find test-and-set used alone in implementation of such primitives as you often don't want to unnecessarily spin and use valuable resources but instead schedule another thread on this CPU.

Comment: For example kernel 5.10 implementation with all it's gory details: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.3/source/ipc/sem.c#L1981
I don't pretend that I understand the code off-hand and it is possibly beyond scope of SO. You may need to read up articles on LWN and dig into the source code.

Comment: `How the processor do that?` Processor is irrelevant, you are in userspace. `semop` may be a system call, then kernel may pause all processes, do the operation and resume all processes if he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some implementation details in Linux 5.4. The source code managing the sysV semaphores is in *ipc/sem.c*.

The *[semop()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html)* system call entry point calls the common internal *do_semtimedop()* function with the *timeout* parameter set to NULL:

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(semop, int, semid, struct sembuf __user *, tsops,
        unsigned, nsops)
{
    return do_semtimedop(semid, tsops, nsops, NULL);
}
```

After some checks on the parameters and permissions, loosely speaking, *do_semtimedop()*  locks the whole semaphore set and calls another internal routine named *perform_atomic_semop()* which makes the requested "sem operations". **This function scans the semaphore set twice**:

1. **First scan loop** determines if any of the operation leads to a negative value for the semaphores in the set. If yes, it returns **-EAGAIN** if **IPC_NOWAIT** is set in the flags or 1 if it is not set. It may also return **-ERANGE** if one of the operations results in a value bigger than the maximum (defined as **SEMVMX** = 32767 in *include/uapi/linux/sem.h*).
2. **Second scan loop** makes the requested operations as the first loop determined that this will not result into negative values for the semaphores. 0 is returned.

```c
static int perform_atomic_semop(struct sem_array *sma, struct sem_queue *q)
[...]
    /*
     * We scan the semaphore set twice, first to ensure that the entire
     * operation can succeed, therefore avoiding any pointless writes
     * to shared memory and having to undo such changes in order to block
     * until the operations can go through.
     */
    for (sop = sops; sop < sops + nsops; sop++) {
        int idx = array_index_nospec(sop->sem_num, sma->sem_nsems);

        curr = &sma->sems[idx];
        sem_op = sop->sem_op;
        result = curr->semval;

        if (!sem_op && result)
            goto would_block; /* wait-for-zero */

        result += sem_op;
        if (result < 0)
            goto would_block;

        if (result > SEMVMX)
            return -ERANGE;

        if (sop->sem_flg & SEM_UNDO) {
            int undo = un->semadj[sop->sem_num] - sem_op;

            /* Exceeding the undo range is an error. */
            if (undo < (-SEMAEM - 1) || undo > SEMAEM)
                return -ERANGE;
        }
    }

    for (sop = sops; sop < sops + nsops; sop++) {
        curr = &sma->sems[sop->sem_num];
        sem_op = sop->sem_op;
        result = curr->semval;

        if (sop->sem_flg & SEM_UNDO) {
            int undo = un->semadj[sop->sem_num] - sem_op;

            un->semadj[sop->sem_num] = undo;
        }
        curr->semval += sem_op;
        ipc_update_pid(&curr->sempid, q->pid);
    }

    return 0;

would_block:
    q->blocking = sop;
    return sop->sem_flg & IPC_NOWAIT ? -EAGAIN : 1;
}
```

Back in *do_semtimedop()*, the return from *perform_atomic_semop()* is checked:

- If the returned value is 0, any waiting tasks on the semaphore set are woken up to run their pending operations before being woken up (i.e. *do_semtimedop()* is recalled for each waiting task). The global lock is released and 0 is returned
- If the return value is negative (-EAGAIN or any other detected error like -ERANGE), the global lock is released and the errno is returned
- If the return value is > 0 (actually 1), the calling task is put to sleep: it is added in the wait queue of the semaphore set. The call is blocked until the task is woken up.

So, to answer the question, there is no intermediate time period where one semaphore operation is done while the other is pending on the same set. There are all done at once or the calling task is put to sleep until it can do it.

Answer (score 2):

> will there be a time interval in which the "old" semaphore has been increased and the "new" one has not?

This is an implementation detail. Implementation may check if the operation is possible, then do the operations, or do operations one after another and if one operation cannot be done revert the operations already done. Or implementation may not do anything at all, up until the next `sem*` operation and query the operations then, etc. The bottom part is that either way only the *observable* state is what matters, and such state where one has increased and the other not cannot be observed by any process, as the operation is done "atomically".

> can this always happen atomically?

Yes, where "atomically" means that no *process* can observe the state in the middle of operation. It doesn't mean that such state "doesn't exists", as the kernel has to query one operation after another. It means that such state can't be observed from a process that uses POSIX api.